# Framerate is always 30 on tokbox/Android

Tags: android, opentok, tokbox

I have an Android app which streams audio/video with Opentok with session in routed mode.

I'm trying to change framerate but it does not matter, it's always streaming at 30fps.

Any thoughts? thanks

```
otPublisher = new Publisher.Builder(mContext).
                        frameRate(Publisher.CameraCaptureFrameRate.FPS_1).
                        build();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The framerate is just a suggestion to the device. If the device does not support that capture framerate then it will not work. From the TokBox Documentation

> If the device does not support the specified frame rate, it will use the closest supported frame rate...

https://tokbox.com/developer/sdks/android/reference/com/opentok/android/Publisher.Builder.html#frameRate-com.opentok.android.Publisher.CameraCaptureFrameRate-